# Swift 3 - Unwind action segue not being called

Tags: ios, swift3

Looked around stackoverflow and elsewhere for over an hour trying to figure this out but I can't seem to find a solution, but feel like I'm close. I have VC1 segueing to VC2 where VC2 loads an image from VC1 and allows the user to add tags to the image.  When I return to VC1, I want to update VC1's image with the tags that got added to the image, and I'm trying to do that with an unwind action.

I have done a ctrl-drag from VC2 to VC2's exit icon and called that "unwindToTossVC" (Toss being specific to the app being built). Per many recommendations, in VC1 I have the following code:

```
    @IBAction func unwindToTossVC(unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    print("In unwind.")
    // custom code
}
```

Here's a screengrab of the relevant parts of my storyboard.

[image: UnwindIssue]

Here's my issue: unwindToTossVC is not getting called. HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a dummy project, I noticed these things please take notice and map to your project

Say I want to unwind segue from VC2 to VC1

First I will make a segue from VC1 to VC2

Second I will implement an unwind action method in the viewcontroller(destinationViewController for unwind) where I want to unwind to, in this case it is VC1

//In VC1

```
@IBAction func prepareForUnwind(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
                print("Unwind Called")
}
```

Now go to VC2 in the storyboard and say I have a button "Unwind to VC1"

Ctrl+Drag from this button to exit icon and select prepareForUnwindWithSegue:

Now when you click on this button it will call the prepareForUnwind Method in VC1

This is my storyboard

[image]

Note: If you have further questions please ask

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did put a button on VC2, then ctrl-dragged from the button to the Exit icon and I got the unwind segue function to run. However, I do not want a button on VC2. VC2 is in a navigation flow and I want to be able to run the unwind segue when the user taps the Back button in the upper left-hand corner of the navigation control.  So, per others' instructions, I ctrl-drag from the VC2 VC icon in the upper bar to the exit icon in the upper bar. That does create an "Unwind segue to "unwindToVC1" action, exactly like the button-exit one, but the unwind func is not called.